# Why does Mary Poppins turn her feet out when she flies?

Tags: movie, mary-poppins

I noticed at the end of the movie, when Mary Poppins flies away, she turns her feet out (super duck-footed). She seems to always do it. Why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe she's a forerunner to Iron Man?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I doubt you'll find any "in-universe" explanation, but [this obituary](http://articles.latimes.com/2000/oct/03/local/me-30469) for Mary Shepard, the original illustrator of the Mary Poppins books, mentions that it was Shepard's idea to depict her flying this way, but the author P.L. Travers preferred a different pose so Mary Poppins didn't end up illustrated flying this way in the book; but apparently Shepard was consulted for the movie, and this time her version "won out" (I imagine because the people making the movie thought it would be a more interesting visual? edit: [this obit](http://www.bayviews.org/baynews/news0201.html) suggests that Shepard may have talked to Julie Andrews about it, and Andrews liked the idea).

> Travers imagined the nanny looking like a doll she pulled out of the
>   attic: a wooden peg Dutch doll with painted black hair and turned-up
>   nose. Shepard bought a similar doll to pose by her drawing board as
>   she made line drawings for the eight Mary Poppins books published from
>   1934 through 1988. The Disney motion picture somewhat changed the
>   period of the story, but adapted Shepard's costume and style for
>   Andrews' character. The author and the artist had many discussions of
>   what the "almost perfect" nanny was to look like--including whether
>   her feet would be in the ballet fifth position as a straight line or
>   fourth position at right angles. The author won in the book versions
>   where Mary's feet are at right angles; but the artist won out in the
>   movie, where Poppins' feet are heels together at a 180-degree angle.

[This article](http://dancelines.com.au/mary-poppins-please-turn-out-your-toes/) mentions that the basic idea to have Poppins stand in a ballet position may have originally been Travers', since she had a background in dance, even if they disagreed on which ballet positions to use:

> why the position of the turned out feet of Poppins? The answer may lie
>   in Travers’ background. Long before she was a writer, Travers was a
>   dancer and actor, performing in pantomimes in Sydney and later dancing
>   as an interlude within Shakespeare productions. In any case, Shepard
>   was just as keen on a dancing Poppins as Travers, deciding that the
>   nanny might be shown standing in a ballet fifth position, the heel of
>   one foot lined up with the toes of the other. Travers objected, hence
>   a compromise, with Poppins more often standing in first, second and
>   fourth positions.